# Running Postgres insert sql using command prompt informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

I am running the below postgres insert sql script through informatica command prompt. Able to run the script successfully.

Only issue is in script we are passing password as hardcoded value but its not secure and moreover not sure how to change it dynamically for dev and prod. Need suggestion how to keep the password as secret and how to change it dynamically for dev and prod. Below is the command we are using and **** is basically where we are passing the password.

PGPASSWORD=***** psql -U username -h host -d databasename -f source filename path

Answer (score 1):

Use `pmpasswd` utility.

1. encrypt the pass using this `pmpasswd newpass`. Assume output is `ABCX6789`
2. Set an environment variable using this `PGPASS = ABCX6789`. Export the variable for UNIX/LINUX.
3. use above parameter `PGPASS` in your `psql...` command. Please note to initiate the psql using infa command line utility.

When password changes, you just have to change the pass in environment variable and not in tool.

This also give you an extra layer of security since you arent mentioning text password in informatica script.

Comment: @Koushik-Thank you for the steps.Informatica has been installed on windows server just wondering how to do this for windows and do I need to perform the above steps within command task itself?

Comment: step1 and 2 will be in cmd prompt whenever they will change password. Step 3 will be onlhy one time - during development.